# Changing timezone in Windows is not reflected in C# TimeZone calls

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

On Windows 7. I am in PST TimeZone. I changed the timezone in Windows to Eastern and then executed this in LinqPad:

```
 TimeZoneInfo tzinfo = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
 tzinfo.Dump();

 TimeZone localZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
  localZone.Dump();
```

[image]

[image]

**Why is it not showing Eastern timezone and why one structure is showing Pacific timezone and the other Eastern?**

Comment: The code probably didn't recompile. LinqPad is only a simulator and probably took the timezone when compiled.

Comment: I verified what you said and tested in VS and it showed both Eastern. Well that's irritating about Linqpad. How do you force a recompile in Linqpad other than restarting it?

Comment: Change the code and it will recompile.

Comment: Oh, there's also a setting called "Always use Fresh Process per Execution" that you can turn on.

Comment: Thanks. You can put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Caches the local time zone.  If you need to be sure that you account for changes the user may have made, you need to call [`TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.clearcacheddata.aspx) before getting the local time zone.

From the MSDN docs (emphasis mine):

> Cached time zone data includes data on the local time zone, the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) zone, and any time zones that are retrieved by using methods such as `FindSystemTimeZoneById` and `GetSystemTimeZones`.
>
> You might call the `ClearCachedData` method to reduce the memory devoted to the application's cache of time zone information **or to reflect the fact that the local system's time zone has changed**.

This probably applies within LinqPad also.