# How do I display the correct timezone name for a country in C#?

Tags: c#, timezone

I am trying to get the current timezone for a country in C# by using the Timezone class. I used `Timezone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName`, however, this returns an incorrect timezone name.

This is what I tried so far:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData();
Console.WriteLine("Local machine's time zone is: " + TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName + " " + TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName + Environment.NewLine);
```

When I change the settings in Windows (currently I am using Windows 10) for my timezone to "Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna" the timezone standard name [should](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/germany/berlin) return "Central Europe Standard Time" (or **CET** for short). The timezone that is returned is "Western Europe Standard Time" (or **WET** for short).

Am I doing something wrong or is this some kind of bug?

I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48202272/timezoneinfo-getsystemtimezones-wrong-timezone-name#answer-48213053) something about having to use something called "[Unicode Common Locale Data Repository](http://cldr.unicode.org/)" - or "CLDR" for short. Am I required to [install a package](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames) anytime I would like to use timezone related code these days?

Comment: Even the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezone?view=netframework-4.8) for `TimeZone` say to not use it anymore. Use `TimeZoneInfo` instead.

Comment: @Sweeper even when using `TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName` I get the same result.

Comment: this sounds similar to [the cached timezone problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45853988/4648586). have you tried it?

Comment: I did not try that yet @BagusTesa but I just tried it now and it does not seem to solve my problem of getting the correct local machine's time zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your cache.  This is just the nature of the data.

For the time zone you described, the data in Windows (for English) is:

```
Id           = "W. Europe Standard Time"
DisplayName  = "Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
StandardName = "W. Europe Standard Time"
DaylightName = "W. Europe Daylight Time"
```

You can use the `IsDaylightSavingTime` method of a `TimeZoneInfo` instance to decide which to pick.

You should not use the `TimeZone` class anymore - it has been deprecated.  Use `TimeZoneInfo.Local` instead of `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone`.

Indeed, the names given by Windows in the `StandardName` and `DisplayName` fields are not ideal.  They often do not align to expectations.  That is why I wrote the [TimeZoneNames](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames) package.  [I also blogged in detail about this problem](https://codeofmatt.com/localized-time-zone-names-in-net/).

With TimeZoneNames, you can get better names for the current time zone like this:

```
var names = TZNames.GetNamesForTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "en-US");
```

For the same time zone as before, you'll now get the CLDR names:

```
 names.Generic  = "Central European Time"
 names.Standard = "Central European Standard Time"
 names.Daylight = "Central European Summer Time"
```

Again, you can use `TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime` to decide whether to show the standard or daylight name.

If you don't want to hard-code the language, use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag`.

Comment: Using `TZNames.GetNamesForTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "en-US");` means I have to provide a string called languageCode. Is there a way I could get this setting from the machine my program would be running on?

Comment: Yes.  See the very last sentence of my response above. :)

Comment: This solution is exactly what I was looking for.